# How to implement both flexible and immediate In-App Update

Tags: android, in-app-update

How Do I implement both flexible and immediate in-app update in app at once and how do i set which type of update i want the user to see.

Comment: does this helps? https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates

Comment: @pz64_ I have already implemented immediate update but actually I wanted to implement both type of updates, as per needs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem which I have implemented for my project, I am using an API to send me if I want to give immediate or flexible update and based on that I have used if-else to run the desired code.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to the user to decide which type of UPDATE they want.
It can also be configured via the remote config variable to decide which type of update they want.

It always returns true whether update type is FLEXIBLE or IMMEDIATE

```
isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)
isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
```

I have already integrated in-app update API in Many Mobile Application and It is running all perfect now. The documentation had this ambiguity.

So you should write your own logic whether you want Flexible or Immediate Update via remote config or server.